How to disable splash screen theme while transition in android 12 by programtically
I am working on OTT tv application. My application complie sdk version is 14 now. While  navigate from Home page to any other page in between my default theme is coming like a screen. Its a splash screen. I confirm with the following logs...
 11-21 11:23:18.023   971  1095 D SplashScreenView: Build android.window.SplashScreenView{690a953 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-0,0}
 11-21 11:23:18.023   971  1095 D SplashScreenView: Icon: view: null drawable: null size: 0
 11-21 11:23:18.023   971  1095 D SplashScreenView: Branding: view: android.view.View{8619290 G.ED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #10204a6 android:id/splashscreen_branding_view} drawable: null size w: 0 h: 0

How can I disable the splash screen while transition? I followed the link to resolve. Disable Android 12 default splash screen . But it won't work. Still the screen is showing. Anyone can help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance.
